# CKEditor is not allowing < sign without >

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor for a project.

When I use [< in content without >](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7L1h.png), it [truncates the content to 1 word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sc4vS.png) after `<` and adds `>` while saving.

I checked in DB, it removes the next p tag

I need to use the less than sign as it is necessary for the project content. Less than 120 is less sensible for user as to `<` 120 and text after that.

Thanks!

Comment: you can try &lt;

Comment: What does 'while saving' do exactly?

Comment: Saves resultant text to MySQL... As CKEditor converts to HTML, it was saving as &lt; but that doesn't help. 

It gets saved as 
<div><p>< dksjfnds></div> 

Already tried: urlecode - decode, stripslashes, allowContent = true for CKEditor config to allow all content etc. 

Thanks!

Comment: What is your other editor configuration? Have you by any chance disabled entities in your editor? Whenever you use `<` in wysiwyg mode (not source mode) editor will automatically convert it to `&lt;`.

Comment: @j.swiderski Yes, tried disabling entities in config. The value can be < or  &lt; result is the same, truncation of next word and auto entry of  >

Comment: If you check CKEditor demo page - https://ckeditor.com/features or SDK samples - https://sdk.ckeditor.com, you will notice that no such issue occurs. This is either some third-party plugin you have used or third-party script causing this. I recommend that you disable your Scripts, third-party editor plugins, clear your browser’s cache and then recheck. If the issue is not there start turning on your plugins and scripts one by one to fin the one causing problem.

Comment: @j.swiderski, thanks for follow up. The switching off other scripts is something I have already tried.. No luck. In these samples, I can type but I can't save. This is not happening while typing.. Only after saving. So not sure if these help. Thanks!

Comment: Does it happen when you switch to source mode and back? If it does there is something in the editor -> configuration or third-party plugin. If it is only happening when you save and load data back into editor then the problem is in your server-side code or DB which changes correctly encoded `&lt;` to `<`. Another possibility is that entity gets decoded when you load data back to the editor. I that case I recommend debugging that HTML in request/response to see where it gets changed.

Comment: It definitely has something to do with the editor. If I do the same process with a text field... There's no problem. Only when I do it with Ck...

Comment: But are these extra tags added when you switch to source mode? Look, CKEditor is JavaScript application and JavaScript can't save data on server. The only way to check if this is editor fault is simply switching to source mode. If tags are not there, please debug your request and see where data gets changed.

Comment: You have told me, you have disabled external scripts. Have you disabled third-party editor plugins (not created by CKsource) and cleared browser's cache before checking http://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser%27s-Cache?